# Automapper - Convert string property to SelectList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I'm just starting to learn AutoMapper in an MVC project. I have a base entity "Attendee" with a string field for Gender (possible values of "M" or "F").

I already have a basic mapping created between my Attendee and my AttendeeEditView objects. What I want to do is convert the "M" or "F" Gender string on the model side to a SelectList on the ViewModel side, with the appropriate value selected in the list.

I think I need a ValueResolver to do this... here's what I've written:

```
public class GenderMenuResolver : ValueResolver<Attendee, SelectList> {
    protected override SelectList ResolveCore( Attendee source ) {
        List<object> items = new List<object>(){
            new{ Value = "F" , Text = "Female" },
            new{ Value = "M" , Text = "Male" }
        };

        string Gender = source.Gender ?? "";
        string selectedValue = new List<string>() { "M", "F" }.Contains( Gender.ToUpper() ) ? Gender.ToUpper() : "";

        SelectList GenderMenu = new SelectList(
            items,
            "Value",
            "Text",
            selectedValue
        );

        return GenderMenu;
    }
}
```

And my mapping code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Attendee, AttendeeEditView>()
.ForMember( dest => dest.Gender, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<GenderMenuResolver>() );


List<AttendeeEditView> ViewModel = Mapper.Map<List<AttendeeEditView>>( Attendees );
```

stepping through I can see this code executes and outputs a proper selectlist. However, I get the following error:

> Mapping types: SelectList -> SelectList System.Web.Mvc.SelectList ->
>   System.Web.Mvc.SelectList
>
> Destination path: List`1[0].Gender.Gender
>
> Source value: System.Web.Mvc.SelectList

First, the ".Gender.Gender" mapping seems incorrect.

But what appears to the root issue... an inner exception message reveals this:

> "Type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' does not have a default constructor"

Can anyone help me identify what I'm doing wrong, or perhaps a better approach I should be using? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're making this more difficult than it needs to be. Not everything needs to be mapped, in fact things like `SelectList`s almost certainly shouldn't be mapped because they're only relevant to a view model, not a model.

So, in your view model just do something like:

```
public string Gender { get; set; }

public SelectList GenderChoices
{
    get
    {
        return new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "M", Text = "Male" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "F", Text = "Female" }
            }, "Value", "Text", Gender);
    }
 }
```

Where `Gender` would be mapped, but `GenderChoices` would just exist on your view model.

Then, in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, Model.GenderChoices)
```

Comment: I like this... I'm also fairly new to using ViewModels, so I appreciate the insight. I'll give this a try.